# Programmatically click on marker and map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to click on a marker and map programmatically, in Google Maps.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a reference to the object you want to click programmatically and call the trigger event on it.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Comment: Throws an uncaught TypeError as `trigger` is not a function of the marker object. Use `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')` instead.

Comment: When referencing other material please provide more specific links than a link to the main documentation. A deep link to the specific page of the documentation and an example of code would be more helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The right way to trigger a marker click/event programmatically is by using `google.maps.event`:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click')
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and write the exact code?  "Cannot resolve symbol 'google'".

Answer (score -2):

you can use  this code for firing click on mao...

```
function onload()
{
 var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
zoom: 14,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
disableDefaultUI: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
       alert('Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng());
//here you can do anything u want to code
}
```